# Why would glDrawElements block on Android?

Tags: android, opengl-es-2.0

I'm trying to optimize a graphics demo written in OpenGLES2 on a Nexus 7 (original).  I have put a timer around a call to `glDrawElements(...);`

```
double before = doubleTime();
glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, getIndexCount(), GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);
double after = doubleTime();

MyLog("%f", after-before);
```

Where `doubleTime()` is a function I wrote to return the current time in seconds using `gettimeofday()`.

It is logging numbers in the neighborhood of 0.06

This seems like an awfully long time to me.  My understanding is that unless an OpenGL call obtains information i.e. glReadPixels / glGetInteger, that it is non-blocking, and the work it does on the CPU is minimal.

Anybody know why this might be?  What does glDrawElements block on?

Comment: Is this the first draw call of a frame?

Comment: It happens every frame, but I should mention that it is preceded by a call to `glBufferData()` which reloads a vertex attribute every frame.  I surmise this is responsible for the 0.06 seconds of work.  I just don't understand why `glDrawElements()` has to wait for that work to happen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your fundamental understanding is correct. OpenGL implementations try to operate asynchronously from the application code as much as possible. The primary motivation is of course to get maximum system throughput by letting the CPU and GPU work in parallel as much as possible, with minimum coupling.

In fact it helps the understanding of performance characteristics and timings if you picture OpenGL calls as requests to *submit* work to the GPU, and not as executing anything directly. Except for some calls that you already mentioned, like `glReadPixel()`, the call will return long before the GPU has executed the corresponding work. Most of the time, it will just have been queued up for later submission to the GPU.

But there is a limit to how asynchronously you can run, or in fact *want to* run. Picture an application that is GPU limited. This means that in a sustained state, the application can make OpenGL calls faster than the GPU can execute them. Unless you slow down the application, it would run farther and farther ahead of the GPU, and more and more work would be queued up. If you did nothing about this, you would end up using an unlimited amount of memory just to store the queued GPU work. For use cases like games you also don't want to have too much GPU rendering queued up because it would increase latency in responding to user input.

Based on this, for GPU limited use cases, the application *has* to be blocked at certain points to prevent it from running too far ahead of the GPU. The question of where and how this happens is fairly complex and system dependent. One simple option is to never let the CPU get ahead by more than *n* frames ahead of the GPU, where *n* might be something like 2. But the actual strategies can be considerably more complicated, and there can be other reasons why it might be necessary to block the application.

Why exactly your draw call blocked in this case is impossible to say without a thorough analysis. The most likely cause is that you got too far ahead of the GPU, and the driver decided that it was time to block you to let the GPU catch up to a certain point. It's also possible that the driver reached a limit on some internal resources, or on available memory, and has to block until something frees up.